# modal popup extender not showing panel on button click

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to use a modal popup extender on my page so when I click a button, it must show a panel.  Here is what I have:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeEmailComplete" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnTesting"
            PopupControlID="pnl" OkControlID="btnOk"
             BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>



        <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" style="display:none;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udp" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlEmailComplete" Visible="false">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest" Text="Testing testing testing"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" Text="OK" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>


        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTesting" Text="Testing"/>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

but i can't get the panel to popup when the button is clicked.  Anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

Your innermost panel has Visible=false.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlEmailComplete" Visible="false">  *(change here)*
```

So, when you press the TESTING button, the ModalPopupExtender correctly causes the outer panel to display, but it's displaying an invisible inner panel, hence you see nothing on screen.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" style="display:none;">  *(this is ok)*
```

To fix, just yank the Visible=false from the outer panel (pnlEmailComplete)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any JavaScript errors and is `pnl.Visible=False;` set on the server-side anywhere?

Make sure you have the `AjaxControlToolkit` referenced properly, [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/ajaxcontroltoolkit) is the easiest way to add the reference.

http://nuget.org/packages/ajaxcontroltoolkit

Comment: I had that in there trying different things, it's removed.  Still doesn't work with or without it...

Comment: I am getting some javascript errors, but pnl.Visible isn't set anywhere

Comment: javascript error:  Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: handler, same error for Parameter name: element

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Btnshow" runat="server" Text="Show" OnClick="Btnshow_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnTarget" runat="server" Text="Target" Style="display: none" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="abc()" />
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="BtnTarget"
            PopupControlID="Panel1">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Width="300px" Height="300px">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnHide" runat="server" Text="Hide Button" OnClick="BtnHide_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnHide" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btnshow" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your answer and why it is the solution rather than posting an undocumented blob of markup. Thanks.